# Using sharpsvn with a local repository

Tags: c#, .net, svn, sharpsvn

I'm using sharpsvn dlls for .NET. I'm new to using subversion, and I'd like my repository to be on a filesystem and not on a remote server.

Is it possible to use sharpsvn like this? I mean, have it checking out from c:\somewhere to c:\somewhere-else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a local SVN repos. I don't know exactly how the sharpsvn library works, but this is how you can do it with the command line svn client.

```
C:\>mkdir svntest
C:\>cd svntest
C:\svntest>svnadmin create testRepos
C:\svntest>mkdir checkoutDir
C:\svntest>svn co file:///C:/svntest/testRepos checkoutDir
Checkade ut revision 0.
C:\svntest>
```

To use from sharpsvn, use the file:/// syntax.

Comment: When SharpSvn requires you to use a Uri (or SvnUriTarget) you can just use new Uri("file:///C:/svntest") or possibly just new Uri("C:\svntest") as the Uri class converts some variants internally.